# Reset a boolean field in all rows in Django DB

Tags: python, django

I have a simple task.

I need to reset a boolean column in a DB table using Django.

Two alternatives:

```
Asset.objects.all().update(my_field = False)
```

OR

```
Asset.objects.filter(my_field = True).update(my_field = False)
```

Which will be better performance wise?

Comment: The first one, has a better perfomance

Comment: The field is a "Not NULL" field.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Please provide a reason....

Comment: Because the first one brings you all the records, the second one too, but the second one has to verify in every record that the field **my_filed** to be True and it takes more time

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Why would the second one bring all records when there is a filter?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres, the `filter` will just add a `WHERE` clause, not actually loading the record into Python objects fro processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends 100% on your particular database.

The first is the equivalent of (ignoring Django name mangling)

```
UPDATE Asset SET my_field = 0
```

The second is the equivalent of

```
UPDATE Asset SET my_field = 0 WHERE my_field = 1
```

These are different queries, since `my_field` could also be `NULL`. (Or there could be database triggers, but there probably aren't.)

Answer (score 0):

Both queries update values using SQL so in terms of Python performance, they should be identical. In terms of db performance, I imagine the later option should be faster since you might be updating a subset of the table (if you use `NullBooleanField`) but that might depend on the db implementation.